# `tf.identity` do not transfer or keep tensor on specified device?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a [vDNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.08124) model with Tensorflow. The main idea here is swap out the feature maps to host memory and fetch it back when compute gradients.

I use the private function `Operation._update_input` to modify the generated computational graph as:

```
def remap_gradients(self):
    for t in self._transfer_ts:
        t_name = t.name.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            identity = tf.identity(t, name='%s/transfer_to_cpu' % t_name)

        for op in t.consumers():
            for i, tensor in enumerate(op.inputs):
                if tensor == t and op != identity.op:
                    op._update_input(i, identity, False)
```

where `self._transfer_ts` are the tensors I want to transfer to host memory. After the remap, I got the new structure:

[image]

which as expect all gradients computations are redirected to the `identity` operation where should run on host memory.

But I still run out of memory when run this model on GPU. It seems the `identity` operation do not functional or it transfer the feature maps back and cache them on GPU again. So what is wrong here?

I have tried to assign to a Variable which is allocated on host memory. But there is a problem: variable need to specify the shape when allocate it. But the batch size is changed in some mini-batch, which will cause the shape mismatch when transfer.

**EDIT1:**

I tried to disconnect the `tf.identity` from the next layer which means the identity value only used for gradients computation. The result seems that data are transferred but slower than the forward computation. It still ran out of memory, but I got this:

```
Current usage from device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, allocator: GPU_0_bfc
  196.00MiB from block2_conv1/Conv2D
```

but if I disabled the transfer function, I will got:

```
Current usage from device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, allocator: GPU_0_bfc
  392.00MiB from block1_conv1/Conv2D
  392.00MiB from block1_conv2/Conv2D
  196.00MiB from block2_conv1/Conv2D
  98.00MiB from block1_pool/MaxPool
```

which seems that some tensors are released, but the memory are not reused.